# React paypal express checkout not working

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I'm using React and the paypal express button was warking fine until now. The express button opens the checkout window but there is no cart or total amount showin and after click the continue button, I got redirected to the summary paypal page.

I can see the transacctions in my account, but the are not completed. Has anyone got this issue before? the paypal example on the right works fine so I think the problem is mine, but the system was working for about six months with no issues.

[image: paypal]

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import paypal from 'paypal-checkout';

payment(data, actions) {
    return actions.payment.create({
        transactions: [
            {
                amount: { total: this.state.totalFee, currency: 'USD' }
            }
        ]
    });
}
onAuthorize(data, actions) {
    return actions.payment.execute().then(function(paymentData) {
        // Show a success page to the buyer
    });
}
...
render() {
let PayPalButton = paypal.Button.driver('react', { React, ReactDOM });

return (
     <div className = "col-sm-3 text-right">
            {
                this.state.env !== undefined ? 
                    <PayPalButton
                        commit={ true }
                        env={ this.state.env }
                        client={ this.state.client }
                        payment={ (data, actions) => this.payment(data, actions) }
                        onAuthorize={ (data, actions) => this.onAuthorize(data, actions) }
                    />
                    :
                    ''
            }

    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I seems to be a problem with the button itself, I just updated the package and refactored the code and now it's working again